# Unable to login via xrdp

Tags: linux

After starting xrdp and trying to login using Windows remote desktop client I get a dialog box with the message 'connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350' and then nothing else happens.  If I then click on the OK button in the dialog box, I am returned to the login screen.

Redhat Enterprise Linux Server Release 6.5 (Santiago)

Answer (score 6):

You must also start `/usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman` before trying to login.

Comment: Eventually I created sym link in /etc/rc3.d which takes care of everything:
S36xrdp -> ../init.d/xrdp

Comment: I don't understand this answer. How do you "start" this?

Comment: @GabrielStaples I no longer have access to that server, but based on my previous comment I would say execute /etc/init.d/xrdp